# Logic error in the Sorts?

Tags: java, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I had been working on sorting of an array constituted of Strings, here's my code for them

```
public static void bubbleSort(String[] values)
{
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            for (int count = 0; count<values.length-1;count++)
            {
                if(values[count].compareTo(values[count+1])>0)
                    swap(values,count,count+1);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
}


public static void selectionSort(String[] values)
{
    int first =0, last = values.length-1,biggest = 0;
    while (last > first)
    {
        biggest = maxIndex(values);
        swap (values, biggest,last);
        last --;
    }
}

private static void swap(String[] values, int first, int second)
{
    String temp = values[first];
    values[first] = values[second];
    values[second] = temp;
}

public static int maxIndex(String[] values)
{
    int index=0;
    for(int count=0; count<values.length; count++)
    {
        if(values[count].compareTo(values[index])>0)
        {
            index=count;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

When I tried to run the bubbleSort through a tester, nothing was printed while the selectionSort only return an un-sorted String.

There's no syntax error in Eclipse, So should I presume there must be a logic error with the algorithms or the code?

Answer (score 0):

**For Bubble Sort**

```
 for (int count = 0; count<values.length-1;count++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<values.length-1;j++)
   {
        if(values[j].compareTo(values[j+1])>0)
                   swap(values,count,count+1);
    }
  }
```

Below is an example of one round of How Bubble Sort works ?

[image: Bubble Sort]

This is only one round we have to do n*n rounds ,

Complexity of Bubble Sort :  `О(n2)`